# Calling a method in the component from a Javascript - Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I need to call a method declared in my Angular component from a Javascript I have written inside the constructor of the same component. My target is to detect the change of a file input filed and upload the file to the server through a service.

I have added this declaration after the imports.

```
declare var $: any;
```

In my constructor, I have written following code.

```
$(document.body).on("change.bs.fileinput", ".fileinput-exists", function () {

    console.log($(this).parent().find('.myImage').val());
    let input = $(this).parent().find('.myImage');
    this._photoToBeSaved = input.prop('files')[0];
    console.log("my file = " + this._photoToBeSaved);
    //upload the image
    () => {
        this.uploadPhoto(this._photoToBeSaved);
    }
});
```

Following is the `uploadPhoto` method in the same component.

```
uploadPhoto(photo: any) {
    console.log("here i am at upload method);
    // call service method to upload
    .....
}
```

However, this does not work.

Note that for the following part in the constructor, I have followed the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329505/angular2-call-component-method-from-javascript-function) question. Can I really do that. Is it correct?

```
() => {
   this.uploadPhoto(this._photoToBeSaved);
}
```

the `uploadPhoto()` method does not get called. Why is that? How to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Posting it here, so that it might help someone in need.

I do not know the reason why the way I have asked in the question does not call the method in Angular2 component. The way to go for is **ARROW FUNCTIONS**.

```
$(document.body).on("change.bs.fileinput", ".fileinput-exists", (event: Event) => {
    alert("fired");
    let photoToSave = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.myImage').val();
    this.uploadPhoto(photoToSave);
});
```

the `uploadPhoto()` method gets called fine now.

Comment: $('.fileinput-preview img').get(0).src;

Answer (score 0):

So your target is to detect the change of a file input and uploading it! doing it using angularjs.
To detect change angular has two in-build function :
`$scope.$watch` an `ng-change`.
However You can use `$scope.watch` Here.

html:

```
 <input ng-model="value" type="file">
```

Angular

```
 //whenever input value will change will automatically updated here
  $scope.value = '';
 //and when $scope.value will change it will trigger this function
 $scope.$watch = function('value' function(){
     //upload code here
 });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this a little more. I find it hard to understand this

Comment: I get the Jquery function fired whenever a file is uploaded to the input field. The problem I have is not being able to call the upload function in the component class from Jquery. I think I will face the same in your answer. Isn't it?

Comment: It's sure that uploadPhoto(element) inside the $scope.$watch will be triggered. Now its up to you.

Comment: That is where I have the problem.  method does not get called